# Android Gallery - Customizing the Individual ImageView ?

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I have created a Gallery with different images added to it. My Gallery Adapter creates a ImageView in the getView function. Now i want to customize this imageview like add a border and rounded corners. How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add borders to your ImageView by setting a background color and a margin. For rounded corners you can place overlay images or use Android's graphic APIs.